# Prerequisites Package Installation

Tags: command-line

I am facing the prerequisite package installation issue on Ubuntu production server. Because I don't have root user privileges so that I couldn't use this command

```
apt-get install libunwind8-dev
```

Comment: Get your system administrator to install it, then.

Comment: You know that you have to use `sudo` right? If you don't know password, then you can't install sofware, unless you edit soudoers file, which is not recommended and for this you need password too.

Answer (score 2):

Since You don't need `sudo` privs to access `apt-get download`, try:

```
apt-get download package
```

Then try to install it using `dpkg`

```
dpkg -i package.deb --force-not-root --root=$HOME
```

or You just can get the `source` of the `package` and then do something like:

```
apt-get source package
cd package
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

Assuming this package doesn't require any specific configuration.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` for `apt-get download`

Comment: @muru Really?  Because on regular Ubuntu (desktop) it is always required.

Comment: @Maria I'm not using Ubuntu, but Debian doesn't require sudo for apt-get download, i checked it just before posting.

Comment: @Maria as long as you can write to the current folder, you don't need `sudo` for just `apt-get download`. `install`, `update`, etc. are a different story.

Comment: @muru @Eska Right, I didn't realize it's a different thing at first because I use `apt-get` only with `install` and similar :P